# MySQL Query: Counting duplicate values in a really huge table

Tags: mysql, select, count

I have this MySQL table:

```
CREATE TABLE `triple` (
  `id_one` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_two` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_three` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

It coontains nearly 10 Million rows. The ids in the middle column ("id_two") can appear in different rows different times.

Short Example:

```
id_one    id_two    id_three
1         2         3
2         2         3
3         2         1
68        98        1
1         4         3
2         4         4
4         5         33
6         5         3
90        5         3
34        5         83
9         3         98
```

Now I want to count the different ids ("id_two"), that is in this example:

```
id_two     count
2     ->  3
98    ->  1
4     ->  2
5     ->  4
3     ->  1
```

How to achieve that efficiently? (It is a one time job...) That is the first thing. The second thing I need is: To count like above and then select only the ids, that have a count of more then let's say 100.

Thank you very much for helping!

Kind Regards
Aufwind

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The basic command to accomplish this is this one:

```
SELECT id_two, count(*) FROM triple GROUP BY id_two;
```

You can store that in a temporary table if you want to …

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE xxx SELECT id_two, count(*) AS c FROM …
SELECT * FROM xxx WHERE c > 100;
```

… or use the result in an outer query …

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT id_two, count(*) AS c FROM triple GROUP BY id_two) t WHERE c > 100;
```

… or use a HAVING-clause (as suggested by Marc in the comments):

```
SELECT id_two, count(*) AS c FROM triple GROUP BY id_two HAVING c > 100;
```

Comment: Assuming you have an index on the id_two column, this should also be fast.

Comment: That easy? I am ashamed... I don't have an index on the id. Shall I better create one?

Comment: Um, why not just use the 'having' clause? `select id_two, count(*) as cnt from trip group by id_two having cnt > 100`. No temporary tables, no subselects...

Comment: @Marc B: Just wanted to show that it is possible to make arbitrary operations on the result set without temporary tables. Updated answer to keep it complete. thx!

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT id_two, COUNT(*)
    FROM triple
    GROUP BY id_two
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 100
```

Answer (score 3):

For question 1:

```
SELECT id_two, COUNT(1)
  FROM triple
GROUP BY id_two
```

For question 2:

```
SELECT id_two, COUNT(1)
  FROM triple
GROUP BY id_two
HAVING COUNT(1) > 100
```

Answer (score 1):

For your "second thing", use HAVING

```
SELECT id_two, count(*) nb FROM triple GROUP BY id_two HAVING nb >= 100;
```

Indexing field `id_two` should give it a performance boost.

Answer (score 1):

For a one-time job on a 10 million row table, I'd just skip the SQL entirely. Trying to use GROUP BY could lock your table for way too long.

```
SELECT id_two FROM TRIPLE INTO OUTFILE('/tmp/idtwo.txt')
```

On a Unix-like system, this will produce a listing with two columns: number of occurrences, ID

```
# sort -n /tmp/idtwo.txt | uniq -c
```

..if you must use GROUP BY, add an ORDER BY NULL to the end of your select statement to save some time. Otherwise MySQL will try to order your groups by [the  default order](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/order-by-optimization.html) (the value of id_two).

Comment: Thank you for the hint to `ORDER BY NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select id_two,Frequency=count(*)
from triple
group by id_two
having count(*) > 1 -- replace 1 with desired threshold
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this should give a `#1054 - Unknown column 'Frequency' in 'field list'` error... Maybe `count(*) as Frequency`?

Comment: You choose the syntax you like. Does mySql not support the `column-name=value` syntax? I prefer `column-name=value` as it makes for far more readable code than `really long ginormous expression' as column-name`.

Comment: Unfortunately, MySQL does not support that syntax. Check http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html. Maybe file a feature request in their bug tracker.